# How to I extract floats from a file in Python?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, loops

So, I have a file that looks like this:

```
# 3e98.mtz MR_AUTO with model 200la_.pdb
SPACegroup HALL P 2yb #P 1 21 1
SOLU SET RFZ=3.0 TFZ=4.7 PAK=0 LLG=30
SOLU 6DIM ENSE 200la_ EULER 321.997 124.066 234.744 FRAC -0.14681 0.50245 -0.05722
SOLU SET RFZ=3.3 TFZ=4.2 PAK=0 LLG=30
SOLU 6DIM ENSE 200la_ EULER 329.492 34.325 209.775 FRAC 0.70297 0.00106 -0.24023
SOLU SET RFZ=3.6 TFZ=3.6 PAK=0 LLG=30
SOLU 6DIM ENSE 200la_ EULER 177.344 78.287 187.356 FRAC 0.04890 0.00090 -0.57497
```

What's the best way to iterate through this file and extract only the floating point numbers?

The 'best' scenario in this case, would be extracting only the numbers similar to "321.997" (which are virus cell structure coordinates) and adding them to a list. In each file that I am looking at, there is 6 numbers like that in each line. After I pull those numbers, I can use the list in a method I've already written to calculate new coordinates for rotating the cell structure to match others in a data set.

Comment: Best in what sense? What are your constraints or goals? How large can your inputs be? Do you need the solution to be portable to older versions of Python? Do you expect a high number of failures or a high number of successes? Do you want things like '0e0' to be treated as a float? What about "1,100.0"? How about culture issues? It's impossible to know what is best for your specific circumstances unless you describe your problem in more details.

Comment: Not homework, I swear! It's a project that takes URL-encoded output from a program called Phaser, and uses the float values to calculate new new x, y, and z coordinates for cell structures.

Comment: @stephenjahl: If it's not homework, then provide some context about what you're trying to optimize.  As @Mark Byers points out, there's no way to interpret "best" without some background.  Homework has no background.  If you have some background, provide a hint as to what *you* mean by "best".

Comment: Easy! "def filterFloats(): return []", as there are no floats in that list, only strings...

Comment: @stephenjahl: Please update the question with your best scenario information.  Please do not comment on a question which you own.  Please correct and clarify the question.  Then delete the comment.  No one is going to read a long thread of comments to understand your question.

Comment: @stephenjahl.  If there are 6 numbers in the same position on each line, then you don't want a filter.  You want to pick values from the correct positions.

Comment: @stephenjahl: You say that "In each file that I am looking at, there is 6 numbers like that in each line" but in your example file that is palpably not true; there are 2 "heading" lines, then every SECOND line contains what you appear to want. When you edit your question, please make sure it is internally consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you display your input in a manner that discourages answerers from examining its structure, and you ask questions like "how do I extract only the floating point numbers", and bury useful information like "In each file that I am looking at, there is 6 numbers like that in each line" in comments, you will get knee-jerk answers providing exactly what you asked for: a list of "floats" that **includes 3 spurious numbers (1.0, 21.0, and 1.0)** at the front of the list.

If you display your data in a slightly more congenial fashion, like:

```
alist = [
    '#', '3e98.mtz', 'MR_AUTO', 'with', 'model', '200la_.pdb', 'SPACegroup', 'HALL', 'P', '2yb',
    '#P', '1', '21', '1', 
    'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.0', 'TFZ=4.7', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_',
        'EULER', '321.997', '124.066', '234.744', 'FRAC', '-0.14681', '0.50245', '-0.05722',
    'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.3', 'TFZ=4.2', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_',
        'EULER', '329.492', '34.325', '209.775', 'FRAC', '0.70297', '0.00106', '-0.24023',
    'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.6', 'TFZ=3.6', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 
        'EULER', '177.344', '78.287', '187.356', 'FRAC', '0.04890', '0.00090', '-0.57497'
    ]
```

there is some chance that people will notice the structure (EULER followed by three numbers then FRAC followed by three numbers) repeated and go "Oho, six numbers per line in his file" and come back with some more useful advice, like:

Start at the beginning, tell us what your file structure is. There is likely to be a better way of getting your information than smashing your file into a list of strings and then attempting to recover from that.

**Update** In the meantime, here is an answer that uses the structure that is evident in your data and comments and will be more debuggable if there are variations in the structure:

```
TAG0 = 'EULER'
TAG1 = 'FRAC'

def extract_rows(tokens):
    pos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            pos = tokens.index(TAG0, pos)
        except ValueError:
            return
        assert pos + 8 <= len(tokens)
        assert tokens[pos+4] == TAG1
        yield (
            tuple(map(float, tokens[pos+1:pos+4])),
            tuple(map(float, tokens[pos+5:pos+8])),
            )
        pos += 8

for rowx, row in enumerate (extract_rows(alist)):
    print rowx, 'TAG0', row[0]
    print rowx, 'TAG1', row[1]
```

Results:

```
0 TAG0 (321.99700000000001, 124.066, 234.744)
0 TAG1 (-0.14681, 0.50244999999999995, -0.05722)
1 TAG0 (329.49200000000002, 34.325000000000003, 209.77500000000001)
1 TAG1 (0.70296999999999998, 0.00106, -0.24023)
2 TAG0 (177.34399999999999, 78.287000000000006, 187.35599999999999)
2 TAG1 (0.048899999999999999, 0.00089999999999999998, -0.57496999999999998)
```

**Update 2** Based on your example file, the following simple code (untested) should do what you want:

```
for line in open('my_file.txt'):
    row = line.split()
    if row[0] == 'SOLU' and row[1] == '6DIM' and row[4] == 'EULER' and row[8] == 'FRAC':
        euler = map(float, row[5:8])
        frac = map(float, row[9:12])
        do_something_with(euler, frac)
```

Note: it's only a coincidence that what you are looking for is "all of the floating point numbers" (which ignores the floating point numbers in `RFZ=3.0 TFZ=4.7` anyway!). What you have is a file with STRUCTURE: two types of SOLU records, and you want the 3 numbers that appear after EULER and the 3 after FRAC in the SOLU 6DIM records. You DON'T want a list of all of those numbers and have to split them up again into (3 EULER numbers and 3 FRAC numbers) times N.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Instead of splitting my file into tons of strings, would I be able to use this method by reading through the file? i.e. `for line in file`? 

UPDATE: I've updated to post to include the file itself, rather than a list of strings.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way.

```
def floats( aList ):
    for v in aList:
        try:
            yield float(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass

a = list( floats( [....] ) )
```

Comment: this will extract integers too, won't it?

Comment: If integers were to be excluded from the list, I suppose a "if '.' in v" clause inside the try block would do the trick.

Comment: @chradcliffe.  No.  You don't need any `if` statement.  First try to convert with `int()`.  If that succeeds, pass.  If the `int` conversion fails, then try the conversion with `float`.  You don't want to add any logic outside the built-in function.  Example `int('12.')` raises `ValueError`.

Answer (score 7):

```
floats = []
all = ['#', '3e98.mtz', 'MR_AUTO', 'with', 'model', '200la_.pdb', 'SPACegroup', 'HALL', 'P', '2yb', '#P', '1', '21', '1', 'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.0', 'TFZ=4.7', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 'EULER', '321.997', '124.066', '234.744', 'FRAC', '-0.14681', '0.50245', '-0.05722', 'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.3', 'TFZ=4.2', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 'EULER', '329.492', '34.325', '209.775', 'FRAC', '0.70297', '0.00106', '-0.24023', 'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.6', 'TFZ=3.6', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 'EULER', '177.344', '78.287', '187.356', 'FRAC', '0.04890', '0.00090', '-0.57497']
for element in all:
    try:
        floats.append(float(element))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Nice touch -- appending the floats to a list keeps the floats useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_float(i):
        try:
            float(i)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False


L=['#', '3e98.mtz', 'MR_AUTO', 'with', 'model', '200la_.pdb', 'SPACegroup', 'HALL', 'P', '2yb', '#P', '1', '21', '1', 'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.0', 'TFZ=4.7', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 'EULER', '321.997', '124.066', '234.744', 'FRAC', '-0.14681', '0.50245', '-0.05722', 'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.3', 'TFZ=4.2', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 'EULER', '329.492', '34.325', '209.775', 'FRAC', '0.70297', '0.00106', '-0.24023', 'SOLU', 'SET', 'RFZ=3.6', 'TFZ=3.6', 'PAK=0', 'LLG=30', 'SOLU', '6DIM', 'ENSE', '200la_', 'EULER', '177.344', '78.287', '187.356', 'FRAC', '0.04890', '0.00090', '-0.57497']
print filter(is_float,L)
```